# convert a byte sequence to a float sequence F# (seq<seq<byte> -> seq<seq<float>)

Tags: f#

I'm a newbie to F# and currently wondering how to convert a byte sequence of sequences to a float sequence of sequences

```
seq< seq< byte> -> seq< seq< float>
```

So I have this following byte sequence

```
let colourList = seq[ seq[10uy;20uy;30uy]; seq[50uy;60uy;70uy] ]
```

I have tried using

```
colourList |> Seq.map System.Double.Parse
```

to create a new sequence with float elements but it does not work. Can someone help me please? I've been stuck on this one for days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Double.Parse` is function that maps string into float. What you are looking for here is a function that maps `byte -> float`. That function is named: `float`.

One answer could be this:

```
let colourList  = [[10uy;20uy;30uy]; [50uy;60uy;70uy]]
let floatList   = List.map (List.map float) colourList
```

We use `.map` operations to apply a map function to each element in a sequences.

Since you have two nested sequences it seems logical that we need two nested `.map` operations to do the mapping you need.

`List.map float` is a function that maps the inner sequence: `byte list -> float list`

We apply this function to the outer sequence using `List.map (List.map float)`to achieve: `byte list list -> float list list`